# Type cast exception while trying to execute array_append function in PostGres

Tags: java, arrays, postgresql, append, prepared-statement

The function **array_append** to append an element to array in postgres has the signature like below

```
Schema   |     Name     | Result data type | Argument data types  |  Type  | Security | Volatility |  Owner   | Language | Source code  |           Description            
------------+--------------+------------------+----------------------+--------+----------+------------+----------+----------+--------------+----------------------------------
 pg_catalog | array_append | anyarray         | anyarray, anyelement | normal | invoker  | immutable  | rdsadmin | internal | array_append | append element onto end of array
```

When i execute it like below with the prepared statement to remove an array element like below ,

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.append("update test set tags = array_append(tags, ?) where id = ?")
pstmt = cursor.prepareStatement(builder.toString());
int queryCount = 0;
pstmt.setString(++queryCount, "2181");
pstmt.setString(++queryCount, "123");
```

I get the following exception

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function array_remove(text[], character varying) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 60
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2284)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2003)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:200)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:424)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:161)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:133)
```

Below is the schema for the table 'Test'

```
Column     |           Type           |   Modifiers   | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
---------------+--------------------------+---------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id          | text                     | not null      | extended |              | 
 tags    | text[]                    | not null      | extended |              |
```

Can someone let me know how to fix this ? However this works when used without PreparedStatement

Comment: Could you please show us the 'array_append' code?

Comment: The built-in array_append function of Postgres does not meet your requirements? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-array.html

Comment: @P.Merkle It's the in-built function I guess

Comment: Also this error occurs only when used with prepared statement. If i execute UpdateQuery with string sql statement appending the parameters then it works fine

Comment: What's in your `sql` variable, or do you mean `builder.toString()`?

Comment: @P.Merkle Yes. That was a mistake. Will correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to cast the first parameter to `text` as defined in your schema:

```
UPDATE test SET tags = array_append(tags, ?::text) WHERE id = ?
```